# Cannot resolve symbol ReserveIntents?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-api

So I have this test app which uses an ReserveIntent. I refer to this site

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#CallCar

Anyway so I always get this error

> Cannot resolve symbol ReserveIntents?

I am a beginner in android so please do understand. Should I import something? I do not understand. 
Pls. do help me.

Comment: `ReserveIntents` is from [the Play Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents)

Comment: @CommonsWare Do I need to download any external sdk not present in the SDK manager. I have downloaded all Google SDK's via SDK manager but is there anything external I have to download?

Comment: No, but just downloading something does not add it to your project. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you so much. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can make it correct.